# DHCPv6 - When is the Status Code Option added to the options field of an IA Address Option?

Tags: ipv6, protocol-theory, rfc, dhcpv6

I was wondering if someone would be able to tell me when is the status code option (OPTION_STATUS_CODE) added to the options field of a OPTION_IAADDR or OPTION_IAPREFIX (RFC3633). The RFC seems to give examples of when it should be included in an IA_TD/IA_NA option but not the address' sub-option.

The RFC specifically allows the status code to be added to an address' options field:

RFC 3315 states:

> The status of any operations involving this IA Address is indicated in
>   a Status Code option in the IAaddr-options field.

RFC 3633 states:

> The status of any operations involving this IA_PD Prefix option is
>   indicated in a Status Code option in the IAprefix-options field.

However, I cannot seem to find an appropriate scenario for this to occur.

For example, a RENEW request by a client with an unrecognised address (per 3315):

> If the server finds that any of the addresses are not appropriate for
>   the link to which the client is attached, the server returns the
>   address to the client with lifetimes of 0.

A DECLINE request by a client with an unrecognised address (per 3315):

> If the server finds that any of the addresses are no longer
>   appropriate for the link to which the client is attached, the server
>   returns the address to the client with lifetimes of 0.

A REQUEST by a client with an inappropriate address (per 3315):

> If the server finds that the prefix on one or more IP addresses in any
>   IA in the message from the client is not appropriate for the link to
>   which the client is connected, the server MUST return the IA to the
>   client with a Status Code option with the value NotOnLink.

In the case of the REQUEST statement above I find it stange that the NotOnLink status is added to the IA option, not the inner OPTION_IAADDR which would make more sense to me.

After going over the RFC a few times, it appears to me that the status code for OPTION_IAADR is just an "optional" extra - which I am assuming can be set along with returning a lifetime of 0 to a client in the case of a RENEW message with an inappropriate address.

Would anyone know if my assumptions are correct or if I am missing a documented use case somewhere (or real world example) for a status code option in the IA Address option field?